# In PowerApps how to configure the inline look up of subgrid component in a form

Tags: windows, sharepoint, powerbi, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

There are three entities Idea,Department and Expected Result. A department can have multiple expected results. An idea falls under a department.The user should be able to add multiple expected results to an Idea .The option list of expected results listed in Idea's subgrid inline lookup should be based on the department of the Idea.

I am developing the App using the Innovation Challenge template provided in the App list.

App type: Model driven app

Type of plan: Power Apps Per User Plan trial